# Getting Registered IPs from Eureka Server

Tags: python, netflix-eureka

Is there any way we can get the service name and ips that are registered in Eureka server using python client?

I checked the python-eureka-client tutorial page but couldn't find anything related to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using https://github.com/keijack/python-eureka-client , please check

```py
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka_client
    
client = eureka_client.get_client()
    
for app in client.applications.applications:
    for ins in app.instances:
    # for ins in app.up_instances:
        print("[%s] %s:%d" % (ins.instanceId, ins.ipAddr, ins.port.port))
```